# Unable to deploy a Karaf kar file containing a ComponentFactory OSGi declarative service

Tags: osgi, karaf, declarative-services

I'm having hard time to get a simple PoC application to work in Karaf 4.2.1 and 4.0.9 (ServiceMix - 7.0.1).

The application tries to create services using a [org.osgi.service.component.ComponentFactory](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/cmpn/org/osgi/service/component/ComponentFactory.html) but during deployment time via Karaf's feature file format I get the following error:

```
15:27:07.969 WARN [fileinstall-/Users/tmoreira2020/temp/apache-karaf-4.2.1/deploy] Unable to install Kar feature br.com.thiagomoreira.application/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT 
org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=br.com.thiagomoreira.application; type=karaf.feature; version="[1.0.0.SNAPSHOT,1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=br.com.thiagomoreira.application)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=1.0.0.SNAPSHOT)(version<=1.0.0.SNAPSHOT))" [caused by: Unable to resolve br.com.thiagomoreira.application/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [br.com.thiagomoreira.application/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=br.com.thiagomoreira.application; type=osgi.bundle; version="[1.0.0.201808301826,1.0.0.201808301826]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve br.com.thiagomoreira.application/1.0.0.201808301826: missing requirement [br.com.thiagomoreira.application/1.0.0.201808301826] osgi.service; filter:="(objectClass=org.osgi.service.component.ComponentFactory)"; effective:=active]] 
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates$MissingRequirementError.toException(Candidates.java:1343) ~[?:?] 
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.doResolve(ResolverImpl.java:392) ~[?:?] 
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:378) ~[?:?] 
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:332) ~[?:?] 
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:257) ~[?:?] 
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:388) ~[?:?] 
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1025) ~[?:?] 
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.lambda$doProvisionInThread$13(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:964) ~[?:?] 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:?] 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:?] 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:?] 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:?] 
Caused by: org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve br.com.thiagomoreira.application/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [br.com.thiagomoreira.application/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=br.com.thiagomoreira.application; type=osgi.bundle; version="[1.0.0.201808301826,1.0.0.201808301826]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve br.com.thiagomoreira.application/1.0.0.201808301826: missing requirement [br.com.thiagomoreira.application/1.0.0.201808301826] osgi.service; filter:="(objectClass=org.osgi.service.component.ComponentFactory)"; effective:=active] 
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates$MissingRequirementError.toException(Candidates.java:1343) ~[?:?] 
        ... 12 more 
Caused by: org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve br.com.thiagomoreira.application/1.0.0.201808301826: missing requirement [br.com.thiagomoreira.application/1.0.0.201808301826] osgi.service; filter:="(objectClass=org.osgi.service.component.ComponentFactory)"; effective:=active 
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates$MissingRequirementError.toException(Candidates.java:1343) ~[?:?] 
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates$MissingRequirementError.toException(Candidates.java:1343) ~[?:?] 
        ... 12 more
```

If I deploy the bundles independently, e.g. one after another without the kar file, the wiring process works well.

The project's code is available at https://github.com/tmoreira2020/poc-osgi-whiteboard

What I'm missing?

Comment: This is a pretty old question out here, but no responses.  Ever figure it out.  I'm hitting a similar problem and it's throwing me that it says my objectClass can't be found when I can find it in the kar file in a plugin it's using.  I even put that class straight into my main code, still same error.